# Can't get Time.use_zone to change Time.zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to setup my rails app to use the timezone set in the User model. The User model saves the timezone as a string and then in the application I am setting the timezone from the current users timezone as described on this page: https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/

`around_action :user_timezone, if: :current_user`

`private
  def user_timezone
    Time.use_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(current_user.timezone)){ yield }
  end`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have any affect on the time zone setting for the app. When I print dates in my views they use the default app timezone and ignore the user timezone. If I just print Time.zone in a view it prints the default app timezone and not the user timezone.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to set the user time zone in the app?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was simply storing the wrong string in my database for timezones. If I set the user timezone from a selection of ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all then it works when I parse that selection as ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(current_user.timezone).